# Possible wrong gradient in my book, need confirmation

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

While reading this chapter about iterative algorithms, I came up with the following function and it's gradient.

[image: page]

I just can't find the same gradient showed. I tried two different approaches and both disagree with the book. Now I'm starting to think they made some mistake and I just need to confirm whether this is the case or not.

By the way, one of my computations is the following.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+te_i)-f(x)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+te_i)^TA(x+te_i) -b^T(x+te_i)- \frac{1}{2}x^TAx + b^Tx}{t} =$$

$$= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\frac{1}{2}(x^TAx + te^T_iAx + tx^Te_i + t^2e_i^Te_i) -b^Tx - tb^Te_i -\frac{1}{2}x^TAx + b^Tx}{t} = $$

$$= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{e^T_iAx + x^Te_i + te^T_ie_i - 2b^Te_i}{2} = \frac{e^T_iAx + x^Te_i - 2b^Te_i}{2} = \frac{(Ax)_i + x_i-2b_i}{2},$$

where $(Ax)_i$ is the ith line of $Ax$. Therefore, $\nabla f(x) = \frac{Ax + x - 2b}{2}$ or $\frac{Ax+x}{2}-b$. Anyway, the resulty doesn't match. Also, if the book indeed made a mistake, what should be the function $f$ to get that gradient?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the first part with the matrix should have two parts one where you increase the transpose of x and one where you increase the normal vector x, similarly to how the product rule is derived

Comment: @Dan Thank you for commenting. I have a question regarding your answer: What exactly is the problem you are talking about? My calculations? The book? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the book is correct the error is in how you handled the limit. I can write up a clear answer to show how to properly deal with said limit

Comment: That's a shame (for me) because I tried to see how would be the derivative in the case of dimension two. My hope was that in this simple case I wouldn't make miss calculations, and in this case what I found didn't match the book. Maybe I got wrong even a simple case...need some coffee :)

Comment: Try expanding $(x+te_i)^TA(x+te_i)$ again. The result has 4 terms, and each one of them involves the matrix $A$.

Comment: This is also one of the reasons I enjoy einstein summation notation so much, it makes calculating these much easier

Comment: @Dan An answer is very desired, for I can't see where I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dan Ok, I just realized what I got wrong. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: And I juuuust posted an answer based on the way I'd have done it :)

Comment: You can derive the gradient quickly by expanding $f(x+\Delta x) $ and throwing away terms that are quadratic in $\Delta x $ (to obtain a first order approximation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this is how I would have handled it, the part containing b is perfectly fine, so in essence I will differentiate the matrix part, all factors of $\frac{1}{2}$ will be moved out front. The first step is fine:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + t e_i) - f(x)}{t} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(x+te_i)^TA(x + te_i) -x^T A x }{t}
$$

I will use the steps involved in proving the product rule, we add zero to the numerator in the form:

\begin{eqnarray*}
& &\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(x+te_i)^TA(x + te_i) -x^T A x }{t} = \\
 & &\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(x+te_i)^TA(x + te_i)-(x+te_i)^TAx + (x+te_i)^TAx -x^T A x }{t}
\end{eqnarray*}

Then split the limit into two limits

$$
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(x+te_i)^TA(x + te_i)-(x+te_i)^TAx + (x+te_i)^TAx -x^T A x }{t} =
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x+te_i)^TA(x + te_i)-(x+te_i)^TAx}{t} + \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x+te_i)^TAx -x^T A x}{t}
$$

Finally factor out like terms in both limits

$$
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0} (x+te_i)^T A \frac{(x+te_i) - x}{t} + 
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(x+te_i)^T - x^T}{t}Ax 
$$

These limits simplify easily (essentially they represent derivatives of the vectors themselves), So this all boils down to

$$
\frac{1}{2}e_i^T A x + \frac{1}{2}x^T A e_i =  e_i^T A x
$$

The last equality usually stems from A being a symmetric matrix

Answer (score 1):

Partial derivatives of that troublesome first term are a straightforward calculation that doesn’t require any particular tricks:$$\begin{align}
\frac\partial{\partial x_i}(x^TAx) &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h[(x+he_i)^TA(x+he_i)-x^TAx] \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h(x^TAx+he_i^TAx+hx^TAe_i+h^2e_i^TAe_i-x^TAx) \\
&= e_i^TAx+x^TAe_i \\
&= 2e_i^TAx \\
&= 2A_ix,
\end{align}$$ using the distributive law in the first step and symmetry of $A$ in the penultimate step. $A_i$ denotes the $i$th row of $A$.

You started down the right track in your own calculation, but when you expanded $(x+he_i)^TA(x+he_i)$ you left out a factor of $A$ in the third and fourth terms, which left you with $x_i$ instead of a second $(Ax)_i$ after taking the limit.

Comment: Alternatively, expand the quadratic form $x^TAx = \sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_ix_j = \sum_i A_{ii}x_i^2+2\sum_{i<j}A_{ij}x_ix_j$ and take partial derivatives.